# Marshalling exceptions across threads (Reactive Extensions)

Tags: c#, exception, ienumerable, system.reactive

I have an IEnumerable sequence which contains some blocking network operations (replaced with some simple yields in the example code below). I am using Reactive Extensions to convert the stream of data coming across the network into an observable sequence.

I'm looking for a way to marshal the exceptions across to the main thread so that unhandled exceptions don't cause my application to terminate. I can't place try/catch blocks on the IEnumerable thread because the compiler does not permit yield return statements inside try/catch statements.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Concurrency;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Main thread: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                var observable = TestEnumerable().ToObservable(Scheduler.NewThread); //Needs to be on a new thread because it contains long-running blocking operations

                // Use subject because we need many subscriptions to a single data source
                var subject = new Subject<int>();

                subject.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Subscriber1: " + x + " on thread: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId),
                    x => Console.WriteLine("Subscriber1 ERROR: " + x+ " on thread: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId),
                    () => Console.WriteLine("Subscriber1 Finished"+ " on thread: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
                subject.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Subscriber2: " + x + " on thread: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId),
                    x => Console.WriteLine("Subscriber2 ERROR: " + x+ " on thread: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId),
                    () => Console.WriteLine("Subscriber2 Finished"+ " on thread: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));

                Console.WriteLine("Press key to start receiving data");
                Console.ReadKey();
                var sub = observable.Subscribe(subject);

                Console.WriteLine("Press key to exit");
                Console.ReadKey();
                sub.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Caught exception on main thread");
            }

        }

        public static IEnumerable<int> TestEnumerable()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                yield return 1;
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                yield return 2;
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                yield return 3;
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your usage scenario _actually_ a console application or is it something with a UI?

Comment: Also, have you considered using an `IConnectableObservable` (via `Publish`) instead of a `Subject` to share the observable?

Comment: The usage scenario is a console application.I haven't heard of IConnectableObservable, I'll do some research. Thanks for your help... will give your solutions a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution depends on whether you have Dispatcher / SynchronisationContext available to you. It is certainly preferable to use one in this scenario.

**Solution 1: Dispatcher / SynchronisationContext is available**

(ie. using WPF, Windows Forms, or a custom Dispatcher loop)

You can use `ObserveOn` + `Catch` to move the error back onto the Dispatcher thread. I've seen this used in a WPF application and it worked well.

How you move your `IScheduler` / `DispatcherScheduler` around is up to you (we used IoC)

```
public static IObservable<T> CatchOn<T>(this IObservable<T> source, 
    IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return source.Catch<T,Exception>(ex => 
        Observable.Throw<T>(ex).ObserveOn(scheduler));
}

// We didn't use it, but this overload could useful if the dispatcher is 
// known at the time of execution, since it's an optimised path
public static IObservable<T> CatchOn<T>(this IObservable<T> source, 
    DispatcherScheduler scheduler)
{
    return source.Catch<T,Exception>(ex => 
        Observable.Throw<T>(ex).ObserveOn(scheduler));
}
```

**Solution 2: No Dispatcher available**

Instead of using `Console.ReadKey()`, use a `ManualResetEvent` and wait on it, then throw the mutable error afterwards:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Main thread: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                var observable = TestEnumerable().ToObservable(Scheduler.NewThread); //Needs to be on a new thread because it contains long-running blocking operations

                // Use subject because we need many subscriptions to a single data source
                var subject = new Subject<int>();

                Exception exception = null;
                ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

                using(subject.Subscribe(
                    x => Console.WriteLine(x),
                    ex => { exception = ex; mre.Set(); },
                    () => Console.WriteLine("Subscriber2 Finished")))

                using(subject.Subscribe(
                    x => Console.WriteLine(x),
                    ex => { exception = ex; mre.Set(); },
                    () => Console.WriteLine("Subscriber2 Finished")))

                using (observable.Subscribe(subject))
                {
                    mre.WaitOne();
                }

                if (exception != null)
                    throw exception;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Caught exception on main thread");
            }

        }
```